# Size error on Collections.Copy(List b,List a) in java

Tags: java, collections, arraylist, copy

I want to copy a list of class to another list of class,but i have an error said that  destination list size is zero but I initialed size for destination list.

```
public class Programs {

public Programs() {
    private int number;
    private String name;
    private int enterT;
    private int burstT;
    private int priority;
    ......
}


 public void SJF(List<Programs> progList){   
    List<Programs> tempProgListMin = new ArrayList<>(progList.size());
    Collections.copy(tempProgListMin, progList);
 }
```

I have error that said size of tempProgListMin is 0 and is smaller than size of progList,
I think, I wrote code correctly but I don't know why it has error.
I need a copy that when i change something in list b(copy one) nothing change in list A
sorry for English!

Comment: `tempProgListMin` doesn't contain any `Programs` object, so it's `size()` is 0. `capacity != size`.

Answer (score 1):

`size()` return the **number of elements** in the list, not the *inicial capacity* that you passed as argument. Therefore, `tempProgListMin` size will be `0`.

You can use this overloaded constructor:

```
List<Programs> tempProgListMin = new ArrayList<>(progList);
```

From [Java Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList%28java.util.Collection%29):

> **public ArrayList(Collection c):**
>   Constructs a list containing the elements of the specified collection,
>   in the order they are returned by the collection's iterator.

Comment: when i use this method, if i change something in tempProgListMin it will change in  progList.

Comment: an other things is that i want to copy List A in List b in a Loop repeatedly and with this method i must make new object repeatedly,

Comment: @user3219993: If you don't want a change in one to be reflected in the other, then you have to do the copying and you have to do it explicitly.  You can't just use `Collections.copy` or the `ArrayList` copy constructor, you have to actually loop through each `Programs` object and copy it explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

As per docs of `Collections.copy(destinationList,SourceList)` method,

`The destination list must be at least as long as the source list`. So, your destination list size seems to be zero and lesser than the lenght of the source list

Answer (score 0):

Consider my example

```
List<String> list1=new ArrayList<>();
list1.add("a");
list1.add("b");
list1.add("c");

List<String> list2=new ArrayList<>(list1);
```

Now it works fine.

Change your code as

```
List<Programs> tempProgListMin = new ArrayList<>(progList);
```

Comment: when i use this method, if i change something in tempProgListMin it changed in  progList.

Comment: an other things is that i want to copy List A in List b in a Loop repeatedly and with this method i must make new object repeatedly